# WAS 7 check servlet requests

Tags: web-applications, websphere

I need to know if a HTTPS request is reaching my application installed on a WAS 7 web server or not...

I can't seem to get this information on the SystemOut.log file, so am wondering where is this information... The HTTP requests are successfull by the way

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a HTTP server in front of WAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AdminConsole and briefly enable an app server trace.  Start here for detail info -> http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frtrb_enabletrc.html